# Retrieving specific data from database

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have made 2 pages: a subscribe page and a download page. Users are able to subcribe to something on the subscribe page. Their choice will be saved in the database. Every user has different kind of choices. This system works fine. However, I do not know how to retrieve the choice of the user from the database. The choices are stored in the database table `wpex_usermeta` in a column called `meta_value`.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, the user with `user_id` 3 has choses `22nl`. How can I retrieve a user his choice(s) from the database.

My php code:

```
<?php

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "Het spijt ons, er is momenteel geen connectie met de server.";
    // echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
     // echo "upload is gelukt";
}

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta';
// This retrieves the data from the database
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name}" );

?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
?>
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Programma:</th><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo "<a href='$mp3_url'>$filename</a>"; ?></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check the manual https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Answer (score 0):

You must select only specific database rows - you must have `user_id`:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name} WHERE user_id=USER_ID_VALUE AND meta_key='programma';
```

Comment: But the program can be anything. I cannot make a seperate column called programma because wordpress does not allow that.

Comment: @JohanDelft Where exactly in this answer is it implied that you would need to make changes to your SQL table structure...?

Comment: "programma" is only example, I think, that this meta key you use for store user choice.

Answer (score 0):

Don't query the `user_meta` table directly. Instead, use [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).

```
$choice = get_user_meta(wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'programma', true);
```

Comment: Where do I have to place that code. Do I have to replace it with ````$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name}" );````?

Comment: You would place the code wherever you need to include the value of the chosen program for the current user; based on your requirements above, I can't give you any more information than that.

Comment: So I would need to place it in the table? You are also using a whole different variable then the one I use ````$retrieve_data````

Comment: I have done that intentionally to highlight that the data returned from `get_user_meta` will be of a different type/structure than your `$retrieve_data` and will require slightly different processing by your downstream code.

Comment: But that means that I will not need ````$retrieve_data```` since ````$choice```` now returns the data.

Comment: That is up to you as the developer, and frankly outside the scope of this answer.